# How do I construct polynomials with complex numbers?

Tags: polynomials

Can I have a simplified version of how to construct polynomials with complex numbers? Can I have an example on how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, it's not at all clear what you're asking. Do you mean constructing a polynomial with complex roots but real coefficients?

Comment: I think so. I just learned it and I don't really get it.

Comment: To be honest, you have to know exactly what you're asking for anyone to be able to answer your question. If your question is really "how to construct a polynomial with complex roots but real coefficients" then you can take any complex number like $1+2i$ and write the polynomial $(x + (1+2i))(x+(1-2i))$ which has complex roots but multiplies out to a polynomial with real coefficiets

Comment: Oh ok. Next time I will try to be more specific. I'm just bad at asking questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A complex polyonmial of degree $n\ge0$ looks like this
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+...,$$
where $a_k,x\in\mathbb{C}$. Here are a few examples:

- $i+3x^2-(1+4i)x^7$
- $2x^4+\sqrt{2}x^5$
- $3/4ix+\sqrt{i}x^9$

As the comments already made clear it is not clear what your asking. If my answer gives you not a solution you wanted, I will delete my answer. You should then specify your question.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks for the example!